# Broken Arduino code

Tags: arduino-uno

#### Errors

> _123:31: error: expected ')' before ';' token 
> _123:35: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token 
> _123:35: error: expected ';' before ')' token

Those are the errors I am having. How can I fix it?

Line 31 and 35 are my problems.

#### Code

```
#define DATA 0
#define LATCH 1
#define CLOCK 2
#define DATA2 3
#define LATCH2 4
#define CLOCK2 5

void setup()
{
    pinMode(LATCH, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(CLOCK, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DATA, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LATCH2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(CLOCK2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DATA2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        digitalWrite(LATCH, LOW);
        shiftOut(DATA, CLOCK, MSBFIRST, i);
        digitalWrite(LATCH, HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }
    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < 256; c++)
    (
        digitalWrite(LATCH2, LOW);
        shiftOut(DATA2, CLOCK2, MSBFIRST, c);
        digitalWrite(LATCH2, HIGH);
        delay(100);
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last for loop is using brackets `(` rather than curly braces `{`

Comment: are you talking about after int c;?

Comment: @JonathanL Two lines under `int c;`. See how you have a `(` there? Its supposed to be a `{` like in your first for loop :)